# Android: RuntimeException, unable to start activity ComponentInfo, toolbar error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've got this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kkk.findyourbook/com.kkk.findyourbook.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.view.View
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.findViewById(int)' on a null object
>   reference

This is weird because it happened just now, I mean I used to run my app without any problems.

My `onCreate()` method looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    getNavigationDrawerItems();

    setupToolbar();
    setupDrawerToggle();

    DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_item, mNavigationDrawerItems);
    drawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    assert drawerLayout != null;
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    sFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout
    if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        Fragment fragment = new SampleFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
        // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        //            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        sFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

`setupToolbar()` method:

```
void setupToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

and in my fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, fragment);

    toolbarInit();

    return fragment;
}

private void toolbarInit() {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitle);
    toolbarTitle.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.cat_my_books));
}
```

Can you help me with this error?

EDIT:

toolbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarIconLeft"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:contentDescription="toolbarIcon" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarIcon"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:contentDescription="toolbarIcon" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` would appear to be returning `null`. I am also unclear how the rest of `toolbarInit()` would work. You might consider editing your question and posting the layout that you are using.

Comment: Check the name of your ids in your layout file. The toolbar is not found and therefore is null

Comment: but it was working a moment ago... I included layout code

Comment: @CommonsWare but why it is null (it is a stupid question...) when a moment ago it was working. DEBUG shows that mToolbar is null, as you said - how to repair that?

Comment: I don't know what to say... I use option `Build` - `Clean Project` and run my app again, it works fine now...

Comment: you need to check getSupportToolbar()!=null before calling setTitle  and setupToolbar method.

Comment: And  use toolbarTitle.setTitle inseted of setText